# Pivoting DataFrame - Spark SQL

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have a DataFrame containing below:

```
TradeId|Source
ABC|"USD,333.123,20170605|USD,-789.444,20170605|GBP,1234.567,20150602"
```

I want to pivot this data so it turns into below

```
TradeId|CCY|PV
ABC|USD|333.123
ABC|USD|-789.444
ABC|GBP|1234.567
```

The number of *CCY|PV|Date* triplets in the column "Source" is not fixed. I could do it in ArrayList but that requires to load the data in JVM and defeats the whole point of Spark.

Lets say my DataFrame looks as below:

```
DataFrame tradesSnap = this.loadTradesSnap(reportRequest);
String tempTable = getTempTableName();
tradesSnap.registerTempTable(tempTable);
tradesSnap = tradesSnap.sqlContext().sql("SELECT TradeId, Source FROM " + tempTable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [databricks pivot](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html), it says `" A pivot is an aggregation where one (or more in the general case) of the grouping columns has its distinct values transposed into individual columns."` And this is not what you desire I guess

I would suggest you to use [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) and [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) to get the final output you desire. You can do as following considering `dataframe` is what you have

```
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|TradeId|Source                                                          |
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|ABC    |USD,333.123,20170605|USD,-789.444,20170605|GBP,1234.567,20150602|
+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can do the following using `explode`, `split` and `withColumn` to get the desired output

```
val explodedDF = dataframe.withColumn("Source", explode(split(col("Source"), "\\|")))
val finalDF = explodedDF.withColumn("CCY", split($"Source", ",")(0))
  .withColumn("PV", split($"Source", ",")(1))
  .withColumn("Date",  split($"Source", ",")(2))
  .drop("Source")

finalDF.show(false)
```

The final output is

```
+-------+---+--------+--------+
|TradeId|CCY|PV      |Date    |
+-------+---+--------+--------+
|ABC    |USD|333.123 |20170605|
|ABC    |USD|-789.444|20170605|
|ABC    |GBP|1234.567|20150602|
+-------+---+--------+--------+
```

I hope this solves your issue

Comment: Yes, I eventually found this option too. Its easier to understand and could even add it to my initial select query.

Comment: Great to hear that @Archilles. And thanks for the acceptance and upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than pivoting, what you are trying to achieve looks more like `flatMap`.

To put it simply, by using `flatMap` on a `Dataset` you apply to each row a function (`map`) that itself would produce a sequence of rows. Each set of rows is then concatenated into a single sequence (`flat`).

The following program shows the idea:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Input(TradeId: String, Source: String)

case class Output(TradeId: String, CCY: String, PV: String, Date: String)

object FlatMapExample {

  // This function will produce more rows of output for each line of input
  def splitSource(in: Input): Seq[Output] =
    in.Source.split("\\|", -1).map {
      source =>
        println(source)
        val Array(ccy, pv, date) = source.split(",", -1)
        Output(in.TradeId, ccy, pv, date)
    }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Initialization and loading
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("pivoting-example").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val input = spark.read.options(Map("sep" -> "|", "header" -> "true")).csv(args(0)).as[Input]

    // For each line in the input, split the source and then 
    // concatenate each "sub-sequence" in a single `Dataset`
    input.flatMap(splitSource).show
  }

}
```

Given your input, this would be the output:

```
+-------+---+--------+--------+
|TradeId|CCY|      PV|    Date|
+-------+---+--------+--------+
|    ABC|USD| 333.123|20170605|
|    ABC|USD|-789.444|20170605|
|    ABC|GBP|1234.567|20150602|
+-------+---+--------+--------+
```

You can now take the result and save it to a CSV, if you want.